# In modern physics, is position still an intrinsic property of a particle?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

In Newtonian mechanics, gravity apart, positions are intrinsic properties of particles. History does affect the current positions, but it has a delayed causality. Now in the case of amplitude/probability functions, particles may be at an undetermined position, yet in a region instantaneously determined by the surroundings.

Thus my question: is position still an intrinsic property of particles or a property shared by a larger system?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93526/discussion-on-question-by-exocytosis-in-modern-physics-is-position-still-an-int).

Answer (score 0):

Defining a "property" of an object as "a number we can assign to that object":

Particles are represented by wavefunctions, and we can define the "position" of a particle with a particular wavefunction as the expectation value of the position operator applied to that wavefunction. This is, in fact, the classical position of the particle in the classical limit.

Comment: OK well reading your answer I see there is a clear misunderstanding, you were right. The expectation value is a number but it represents a truncation of what is known of the system. I am not merely talking about this output value but about everything that allows its calculation. So I am not talking about position as a single point in spacetime either and this is probably what I have not made sufficiently clear.